# How to load xml configuration from stream using apache commons?

Tags: java, apache-commons-config

I would like to use apache commons configuration 1.10 to manage xml configurations.

My configuration is in a remote server, so I need to read it from a stream.

Something like `java.util.Properties` that has method `load` to read from a stream.

```
byte[] streamData=getConfigStream();
Properties p = new Properties();
p.load(new ByteArrayInputStream(streamData));
```

Checking the documentation I have not found anything that could help me.

Can anyone please help me how to get the required output?

Comment: Anything wrong with [XMLConfiguration#load(InputStream)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/javadocs/v1.10/apidocs/org/apache/commons/configuration/XMLConfiguration.html#load%28java.io.InputStream%29)?